# Is there a way to force my app to render above the (on screen) navigations buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I avoid the navigation buttons from being rendered on top of my app?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oh you're looking for "Immersive Full Screen Mode" I believe.

You have to set the to `setSystemUiVisibility()` to `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE`

Check out this link here to learn more
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make your application fullscreen by hiding bottom navigation bar using this code:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

For more information you can read official page: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html